# How to dismiss UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I added a `UIPageViewController` for instructions in my new game, and I want to dismiss the `UIPageViewController` after the user pressed the "GOT IT" button on the last `UIViewController` that connect to the `UIPageViewController`

I've tried this so far:

```
[self.pageVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And it doesn't remove the `UIPageViewController`, Why that?

And how can I dismiss it?

In order to show/present the `UIPageViewController` I do this:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.pageVC];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageVC.view];
[self.pageVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try the opposite calls you have described:

```
[self.pageVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.pageVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the solution I found here and in other posts, because I called `dismissViewController` in one of the children views of the pageViewController, so I didn't dismiss the pageViewController itself, just the shown children view.

Turns out, I found a quick way to dismiss the pageViewController from one of its subViews by pressing a button: just connect this button to the Exit button in the storyboard to unwind (and provide the unwind method in the presenting vc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss the UIPageViewController from a button from within one of the pages, you could add the below code, in the button action. This is similar to the answer given by Alex Peda, the difference being the reference to the pageViewController is through the parentViewController property.

let pvc = self.parentViewController as! UIPageViewController

//remove the page controller content view from the superview.
 pvc.view.removeFromSuperview()

//remove the pageviewcontroller from its parent view controller.
 pvc.removeFromParentViewController()

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 / XCode 9:

While all the proposed answers didn't work for me, this simple line did work:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```